# Checking user input for boxing sim engine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a simple Boxing sim engine and have got things working fairly well. A few months ago I was instructed to avoid copy and pasting code and to try and "conserve my logic".

Anyways, I feel I have done a fairly good job overall but there is one area (posted below) that I feel definitely has room for improvement:

```
print ("1)Joe Smith\n2)Mike Jones\n3)Steve Roberts\n")
boxer1 = input("Choose a fighter: ")
boxer2 = input ("Choose his opponent: ")
if boxer1 == '1':
    B1 = JS
elif boxer1 == '2':
    B1 = MJ
elif boxer1 == '3':
    B1 = SR
if boxer2 == '1':
    B2 = JS
elif boxer2 == '2':
    B2 = MJ
elif boxer2 == '3':
    B2 = SR
```

`MJ`, `JS`, and `SR` are all variables for objects in my Boxer class. My concern is that I will have to continue adding four lines of code for each boxer I add to the program. While I don't mind typing each line out, I realize there may be a much more efficient way to approach this that I'm not seeing. I realize this isn't a major issue but, as I mentioned, this program is mainly for practice and therefore I want to make sure I'm programming as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each `Boxer` object has a `.name` attribute…

```
BOXERS = [None, JS, MJ, SR]
for i in range(1, len(BOXERS)):
    print("%d) %s" % (i, BOXERS[i].name))
boxer1 = BOXERS[int(input("Choose a fighter: "))]
boxer2 = BOXERS[int(input("Choose his opponent: "))]
```

You want to generate the menu using the names already in the boxer objects, and retrieve the result with an array lookup.

Note that with this solution, you'll get an `IndexError` if the user picks an invalid entry.  You should decide how such errors should be treated, since your original code also lacked error handling.